# any difference between laut and zufolge?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

Is there any nuance between 'laut' and 'zufolge' in terms of usage/suitable context?
I have the following understanding:
'laut' is used when conveying a fact stated by a source (study/organisation...etc.)
'zufolge' is used when deducing an act/measurement that has to be taken based on a fact provided by a source.
Is this correct? Or can the two be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*laut* and *zufolge* are close synonyms as you have already stated - I would only see a small difference between them, based on the words they are derived from:

- "laut" simply means someone has stated a simple fact, you are repeating it
- "zufolge" means the argument may be more complicated, and consists of a number of statements or a train of thought you need to "follow up" with.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such difference, both can be used interchangably.

> Laut (des) Polizeibericht(es) gab es keine Verletzten.
>
> Dem Bericht der Polizei zufolge gab es keine Verletzten.

*Laut* is often used for shorter sentences.

Answer (score 0):

No, both prepositions mean that you are repeating a statement from a third party and cannot personally vouch for it. In that respect the two words are interchangeable.

If I had taken my own measurement, I would say

> *Nach* meinen Messungen beträgt die Lücke 3mm.

You wouldn't use *zufolge* to report your own measurement, unless perhaps you'd taken it long ago, noted it down in a diary, and are now talking about what the diary says rather than what you saw.